# Can we filter by a Boolean Formula field during the McConnect Sync?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

I am trying to sync Sales cloud with Marketing Cloud. I have 3 parameters to check before I bring the data into marketing cloud. I decided to create a boolean formula field on the Sales cloud and use that as a criteria to sync the data across both the platforms. Is it possible? As I am reading everywhere that we can only use boolean fields to sync the MCConnect.

Answer (score 1):

I already did exactly this for a client and it worked like a charm. So, **yes**.

However, be careful when syncing formula fields into marketing cloud. Formula field values only update in your synchronized data extension if an update to the record has happened since the last sync run. I ran into this issue myself...

The behaviour is documented [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_implement_synchronized_data_sources_best_practices.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null)

Comment: is it better to set up the boolean field in Salesforce as a "Sync_to_MC" or "Do_Not_Sync_to_MC"? I'm trying to consider the pros and cons of both.

Comment: @GregBeazley it doesn't really make a difference on the technical side. It's rather a matter what is easier to understand by your users and how it fits the pattern you govern data access and transfer.